# Get ALL the tweets

Tags: ruby, twitter

Is there a way to get ALL tweets(or at least 3000) of a certian user using the Twitter Gem?

```
Twitter.user_timeline("BarackObama")
```

Doesn't return as many tweets as expected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `user_timeline` only returns the latest (up to) 200 tweets [1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) with a single request. You could use multiple requests (getting the ID of the last tweet of each request and using the `max_id` parameter to request older tweets) but you'll want to read up on rate limiting to ensure that you don't get blocked for excessive requests. I expect your application will need a caching solution of some form to prevent this from happening.